# Import data from MondoDB localhost to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

I have this database in MongoDB Compass interface which is stored (not sure if this is the right way to describe it) in localhost:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsMPC.png)

Is there a way to export the data from there and import it into MongoDB cloud version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first connect `mongodb compass` to local db and exports data , then connect `mongodb compass` to mongo atlas and import exported data